# Big figure has 4*3 subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have big figure that contains 4*3 subfigures but its not appearing correct. It's taking alot of space. So if anyone could advise. This pics shows the output [image: result] and this is the script used

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\caption{aaa}
\label{fig:rulascore}
\end{figure*}
```

Edit:

I've solved this by cropping each photo using clip function. This thing now is that there is a big white space from the top i don't know how to remove it? [image: issue]

Comment: are you using the `subcaption` package?

Comment: What do you mean by "not correct"? What is correct? Also, please always create a complete example that show the problem, starting with `\documentclass`, containing all necessary packages, and ending with `\end{document}`. It's just a courtesy towards those who wish to help, making it easier for us (we can just copy-paste the entire thing and compile it), as well as making sure we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added a pic showing the resulted image

Comment: With `subfig` package, it shouldn't act that way. There must be something in your file that causes this behavior. Can you provide a MWE? Strip down your file until you can reproduce the odd behavior with the most minimal amount of *compilable* code and paste that into your question.

Comment: I've solved this by cropping each photo using clip function. This thing now is that there is a big white space from the top i don't know how to remove it?

Comment: You can force reducing space with `\vspace{-5mm}` to reduce it 5mm.  However, this is like trying to fit a screw in a wood piece by hitting it with a hammer.

Comment: @user1460166 Your figure floats, so if it doesn't fit on the previous page, LaTeX puts it in a new page and puts it in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[ht]
....
\end{figure*}

\null
```

Comment: If I want to add a caption or label for each row and column, how can i do this? for example i want to write in the begining of row 1 a label named "level 1" and the same on top of column 1, and for the rest of columns and rows?

Comment: then do not define an empty sub caption: `\subfloat[ list entry ][ sub-caption ]{ body }`

Comment: I need it for the whole row not under each figure

Comment: after three subfloats write `\par here comes your text \par`

Comment: the figure i'm working in has 30 figs, 5 rows 6 cols. What I want to do is: in thr begining of every row write some text but i want it to be written vertical not horizontal. For the colomns I want to write a text and group it for each two columns, so for example on the top of col1&2 write data1 which will be centered between the 2 columns. I'm sorry for disturbing you but this is really difficult for me. Thanks

Comment: you can use minipages: `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth} ... \end{minipage}` for the multi line labels.